# can anyone explain , why this code is not working

Tags: python, string

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLastWord(self,s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        len=0
        res=0
        print(len(s))
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] !=" ":
                len+=1
            else:
                res=len
                len=0
        if len!=0:
            return len
        else:
            res
nitesh=Solution()
s='Hello World'
print(nitesh.lengthOfLastWord(s))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\dsa\python\58.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(nitesh.lengthOfLastWord(s))
  File "d:\dsa\python\58.py", line 9, in lengthOfLastWord
    print(len(s))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
PS D:\dsa\python>
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips in debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name your variable as the name of reserved keyword or built in function then that will overwrite the definition of that keyword or function. So, when you use that keyword or function that will not work according to original keyword or function. It will work as variable only... That's why that error is saying, int object is not collable...  Always remember when error has collable word it is about (), and if error has subscriptible word it is about [] so accordingly find your solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you've defined another variable `len=0` inside the method.

`len(s)` would now result in calling method with variable `s` on an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Name your variables appropriately.
Don't Name your variable with reserved keywords or built-in functions.

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLastWord(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        length = 0
        res = 0
        print(len(s))
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] != " ":
                length += 1
            else:
                res = length
                length = 0
        if length != 0:
            return length
        else:
            res


nitesh = Solution()
s = 'Hello World'
print(nitesh.lengthOfLastWord(s))
```